# Killing old Activity in current Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a main activity.When a button(on main activity) is pressed , a newactivity1 starts and main activity is onPause. For example again when a button in newactivity1 is pressed , a newactivity2 starts.But in this case,I want to kill mainactivity before newactivity2 start.How can I do that ?

Comment: Because when user pressed back button on device , Application go back to main activity.

Comment: depends on the launch mode, but i guess it should be back on the newactivity1. anyway, start newactivity1 with startForResult, and in onactivityresult in the main, simply call finish

Comment: use finish() when you start new activity..

Comment: I solved problem with implementing backButton listener.Thanks for all advice..

Answer (score 1):

write `android:noHistory="true"`  in our Mani Fest Like

```
<activity android:name=".ClassFileName" android:noHistory="true" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />
```

This Will kill Your Activity  and no trace Will be there when you go back to previous Activity

Comment: when newactivity1 starts , mainactivity is killed automatically ? 
But I want mainactivity onPause , only it will be killed when newactivity2 starts.

Answer (score 0):

in newactivity1 write

```
this.finish();
startnewactivity...
```

Comment: but this.finish() kills newactivity1.Right ? I want to kill mainactivity that is onPause

Answer (score 0):

Use `finish()` for closing an activity. where you are calling `startActivity();`

Comment: finish() kills mainactivity or newactivity1.Which one ?

Comment: If you use in main activity it kills main activity,

Comment: use finish() in onPause() of main activity it kills main activity only.

Comment: Hmm ok.Where is onPause() method of mainactivity ?

Comment: @Override
 protected void onPause() {  
  super.onPause(); finish()
 } add this code in your main activity

Comment: Ok thx for help.Just last question : How can I call this code part , when the button pressed on newActivity1

Comment: i Did't get you call means what do you want to do

Comment: When user press a button on newactivity1 , I want mainactivity kill and start newactivity2.

Answer (score 0):

call that ActivityforResult:

use A`ctivity.finishActivity()` to `finish` an `Activity` started by `startActivityForResult()`.